# Combination of letters as parameters in python

Tags: python

I wondered if there is a way - didn't find in on the internet but I heard it was possible- to get many parameters in a python script as a combination of letters ? I explain myself : if the user wants to send many optional parameters
Example : If the options are tiger, frog, cat and dog: instead of writing

```
python ./myScript.py --tiger --frog --cat --dog
```

To write :

```
python ./myScript.py --tfcd
```

Is there a way to do that ?

Thanks

Comment: I think `getopt` does that (with only one dash `-tfcd`) using short opts.

Answer (score 8):

[`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#module-argparse) can take both short and long arguments. Short arguments [can be combined](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#option-value-syntax) "as long as only the last argument (or none of them) requires a value."

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-t', '--tiger', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('-c', '--cat')
print(parser.parse_args())
```

Usage:

```
>> python test.py -tcToonses
Namespace(cat='Toonses', tiger=True)
```